# PHP Compare two dates in format 2011-05-16T09:39:14+0000 (facebook datetime format)

Tags: php, facebook, datetime, date

In PHP I want to compare 2 dates in this format:  2011-05-16T09:39:14+0000

```
$datedeb="2011-05-18T01:25:18+0000";
$datefin="2011-05-16T09:39:14+0000";
```

I have PHP5.1.6 for your information.

Answer (score 7):

You can use PHP's [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. This converts them into the timestamps, which means you can compare them like normal numbers

```
    $datedeb = strtotime("2011-05-18T01:25:18+0000"); 
    $datefin = strtotime("2011-05-16T09:39:14+0000");
    
    if ($datedeb > $datefin) {
        //$datedeb is larger (later) than $datefin
    }
```

Comment: It also seems to consider the time zone correctly (at least in PHP/5.3, I have no 5.1 to test that).